# Input missed values with mean of nearest neighbors in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[676, 0, 670, 0, 668], index=['2012-01-31 00:00:00','2012-02-29 00:00:00',
                                                     '2012-03-31 00:00:00','2012-04-30 00:00:00',
                                                     '2012-05-31 00:00:00'])  
df.index.name = "Date"
df.columns = ["Number"]
```

Which looks like:

```
              Number
Date    
2012-01-31 00:00:00 676
2012-02-29 00:00:00 0
2012-03-31 00:00:00 670
2012-04-30 00:00:00 0
2012-05-31 00:00:00 668
```

How can i input 2nd and 4th values with (676+670)/2 and (670+668)/2 correspondinly?

I can save values as `np.array` and imput them in array, but that's rediculous!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use `where` method and specify to replace any `0` with `np.nan`. Once we have specified `0` to be `NaN` we can use `fillna` method. By using `ffill` and `bfill` we fill all `NaN` with the corresponding previous and proceeding values, add them, and divide by 2.

```
df.where(df.replace(to_replace=0, value=np.nan),
 other=(df.fillna(method='ffill') + df.fillna(method='bfill'))/2)

                     Number
Date                       
2012-01-31 00:00:00   676.0
2012-02-29 00:00:00   673.0
2012-03-31 00:00:00   670.0
2012-04-30 00:00:00   669.0
2012-05-31 00:00:00   668.0
```

Comment: could you please provide a little explain?

Comment: @LadenkovVladislav Does that make sense now?

Comment: Thanks! Wonderfull methods!

Comment: Is this possible for more than one NaN value ? How would that look like?

Answer (score 3):

@spies006 answer can be adapted to:

```
df.where(df.replace(to_replace=0, value=np.nan).isna(), other=(df.fillna(method='ffill') + df.fillna(method='bfill'))/2)
```

It can be simplified to this:

```
df.where(df.values == 0, other=(df.fillna(method='ffill') + df.fillna(method='bfill'))/2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#use apply to fill the Number with average from surrounding rows.
df['Number'] = df.reset_index().apply(lambda x: df.reset_index()\
                               .iloc[[x.name-1,x.name+1]]['Number'].mean() \
                               if (x.name>0) & (x.Number==0) else x.Number,axis=1).values

df
Out[1440]: 
                     Number
Date                       
2012-01-31 00:00:00   676.0
2012-02-29 00:00:00   673.0
2012-03-31 00:00:00   670.0
2012-04-30 00:00:00   669.0
2012-05-31 00:00:00   668.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `replace()` method to replace the `0`'s with `np.nan` and then use the method `interpolate()`:

```
df.replace(to_replace=0, value=np.nan, inplace=True)
df.interpolate(inplace=True)

                     Number
Date                       
2012-01-31 00:00:00   676.0
2012-02-29 00:00:00   673.0
2012-03-31 00:00:00   670.0
2012-04-30 00:00:00   669.0
2012-05-31 00:00:00   668.0
```