# Fill missing values by multiple date columns with the mean of previous and forward specific rows

Tags: python, pandas

So this is my DataFrame:

Basically what's in there:

- There is `Query-Date` column, and **foreach** `Query Date` date, there are 30 `Check-In` days forward, and **foreach** `Check-In` date there are 5 days forward.

**Note:** The time formart is Day/Month/Year

**Note:** The hotel name is the same for every row, only the `Price` and `Nights` columns are different ( and the dates )

- There is `Nights` column, it's basically **subtraction** between `Check-out` and `Check-In`

An example for a DataFrame:

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
| Query-Date | Check-In  | Check-Out | Hotel Name | Price | Nights |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
| 1/1/2000   | 1/1/2000  | 2/1/2000  | HotelName1 | 10    | 1      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            |           | 3/1/2000  | HotelName1 | 21    | 2      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            |           | 4/1/2000  | ...        | ..    | 3      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            |           | 5/1/2000  | ...        | ..    | 4      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            |           | 6/1/2000  | ...        | ..    | 5      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            | 2/1/2000  | 3/1/2000  |            |       | 1      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            |           | 4/1/2000  |            |       | 2      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            |           | 5/1/2000  |            |       | 3      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            |           | 6/1/2000  |            |       | 4      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            |           | 7/1/2000  |            |       | 5      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            | 3/1/2000  | 4/1/2000  |            |       | 1      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            |           | 5/1/2000  |            |       | 2      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            |           | 6/1/2000  |            |       | 3      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            |           | 7/1/2000  |            |       | 4      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            |           | 8/1/2000  |            |       | 5      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            | ...       |           |            |       |        |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            | 30/1/2000 | 31/1/2000 |            |       | 1      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            |           | 1/2/2000  |            |       | 2      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            |           | 2/2/2000  |            |       | 3      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            |           | 3/2/2000  |            |       | 4      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            |           | 4/2/2000  |            |       | 5      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
| 2/1/2000   | 2/1/2000  | 2/1/2000  |            |       | 1      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            |           | 3/1/2000  |            |       | 2      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            |           | 4/1/2000  |            |       | 3      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            |           | 5/1/2000  |            |       | 4      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            |           | 6/1/2000  |            |       | 5      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            | 3/1/2000  | ...       |            |       |        |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
```

Now, in some rows, there are missing dates, so for example we could find something like this:

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
| 3/1/2000   | 3/1/2000  | 4/1/2000  |            |       | 1      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            |           | 6/1/2000  |            |       | 3      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            |           | 7/1/2000  |            |       | 4      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            | 4/1/2000  | 5/1/2000  |            |       | 1      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            |           | 6/1/2000  |            |       | 2      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            |           | 7/1/2000  |            |       | 3      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            |           | 8/1/2000  |            |       | 4      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|            |           | 9/1/2000  |            |       | 5      |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
```

We can notice that for the `Query-Date` which the value "3/1/2000" and for the `Check-In` "3/1/2000" there are two missings: the Date "5/1/2000" ( 2 Nights ) and "8/1/2000" ( 5 Nights )

What I want is to add these days, with the same Hotel Name and with the price of the mean of the closest previous row with the same `Nights` value with the closest forward row with the same `Nights` value

But this thing is more complicated because the missing can be for a whole `Query Date` or even few.

So basically I found several topics:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19324591
  Basically they say that the Date should be the index, and then we can use the `pd.date_range` and `reindex`, So what I did is to determine these 3 columns: `Query-Date`, `Check-In`, `Check-Out` to be the index:

`pd.set_index(['Query Date', 'Check-In', 'Check-Out'], inplace=True)`

I also can find the min and max value of Query-Date, but I couldn't find a way to make a range for 3 columns.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44102947/11356272
  In this topic there's a code to fill these null gaps the previous and forward one, but it's not really my case, because I don't need the LAST previous and forward rows for the mean, but the the LAST previous and forward rows **with the same nights**.

I need something like that in ***pseudo code***:

```
query_date = min(pd['Query Date'])
while(query_date != max(pd['Query Date'])):
   for(i in range(0, 30 + 1)):
       for(j in range(0,5 + 1)):
           if(check if row with Query-Date: query_date
                            and Check-In: query_date + (i days)
                            and Check-Out : query_date + (i + j days) is not exists):
                  add to pd new row with these Query-Date, Check-In, Check-out with price: (The last price value with the same + the forward price value with the same amount) / 2
```

Hopefully you guys could help me do that.